# 'INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST' Even when the value is present in picklist field

Tags: picklist, configuration, dependent-picklist

I have created a field of datatype picklist and added some values in it. And checked 'Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set.' and 'Controlling Field' as Country. 
The data is loaded by an excel sheet were the picklist values are pushed in. The values are same as what is there in sfdc. I have verified it many times. 
My doubt is that the excel sheet does not have any Country value in it. Can this be causing the error: `Status code [INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST].  Message [bad value for restricted picklist field: test].`

Is Country required when I have checked 'Controlling Field'?

Comment: Hi Nagendra, yes you may need to include country as well during data load, if not already there on records. Otherwise how would salesforce know whether you are entering correct value as per the controlling field or not.

Comment: Also if you have record types enabled on the object, the picklist value must be enabled for the record type being used.

Comment: Also this article may be useful https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Unable-to-create-record-on-custom-object&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Hi @gorav I did not understand the 5th and 6th point. I am new in salesforce, coming from java background.

Comment: I had to read it twice, it's not very clear!  I think what it is saying is that creating a record where a dependent picklist field is set without setting the controlling field will trigger this error when the field is a restricted picklist.  In this example, the dependent picklist field can be set by having a default value itself, or by having a default value for the record type.  Setting the controlling field should resolve the error.